# How to make text float to the right of a canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas, textbox, css-float

I have been trying to make a textbox (of fixed size) appear directly to the right of a canvas (float right makes it go too far to the right), but haven't had much success. As of now, the textbox keeps appearing directly above the canvas.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="labelMaker"><label>Labs:</label></div>
        <canvas id="can" width="680" height="485"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.labelMaker {
    border:solid;
    width:150px;
    height:100;
}

.wrapper canvas {
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
}
```

Any suggestions to fix this? In addition, I was thinking of putting a header above the canvas and textbox, but was worried that this would affect the coordinates on the canvas if I used a different device with different dimensions or zoomed in/out since if you zoom too much, the text wraps into a new line. Would this actually be a problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .labelMaker{
        border:solid;
        width:150px;
        height:100;
        right: 170px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper canvas {
         margin-right:180px;
        float:left;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` on the parent, then `order: -1;` on the canvas to make it the first element in the container. Also applied the border/width/height of `.labelMaker` to `.labelMaker label` instead, and assigned `display: block;` so it will create layout better than an inline element.

```css
canvas {
  background: #ccc;
}

.labelMaker label {
  border: solid;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100;
}

.wrapper canvas {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

canvas {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="labelMaker"><label>Labs:</label></div>
    <canvas id="can" width="680" height="485"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="left" style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;">
    <canvas id="can" width="680" height="485"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="left" style="float:left;">
     <div class="labelMaker"><label>Labs:</label></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This makes the label go too far to the right though. How do you make it so that the text is like 5 pixels to the right of where the canvas stops?

Comment: I have just edited the answer, now it does what you need

Comment: For some reason, it is making the textbox float over the right third of the canvas. However, I did get a solution from someone else so thanks anyways!